# Calculate Redox Potential

Tags: reference-request, gaussian, solvation, redox

I am interested in calculating some redox potentials of organic compounds (H,C,N,O,F,Cl,Br) in organic solvents such as MeCN.  I do not need absolute agreement with experiments since this is just a first pass to identify some potential candidates for experiments, so I am looking for the best simple approach to this problem.  An accuracy of +/- 0.5V would be sufficient for example, if this is doable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several protocols. Since you mention that you're mostly looking for trends, I'll give the faster method, e.g. by Jason Gilmore:

"Expanding and Testing a Computational Method for Predicting the Ground State Reduction Potentials of Organic Molecules on the Basis of Empirical Correlation to Experiment"
[*J. Org. Chem.* **2012**, 77, 15, 6423–6430](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo300853k)

- Optimize the geometry of the neutral and charged species in gas phase (e.g., a faster optimization)
- Optimize the geometry of the neutral and charged species in solution (e.g., using a polarizable continuum model for your solvent) with a good density functional and basis set.

The 2012 paper from Gilmore mentions optimizing in the gas phase and taking single point energies in solution.

I'd recommend at least:

- Using a "better" basis set (e.g, from the def2 or pc- series basis sets)
- Using dispersion correction (this likely won't make much difference but will give you better energies)
- Using, e.g. $\omega$B97X-D3 or some newer functional (although B3LYP/6-31G* still works remarkably well)

Anyway, the main point is this:
Take the difference in total energy between the optimized neutral molecule ($S_0$) and the radical cation or radical anion ($D_0$) **in the solution calculation**.

This is the ionization potential for that species in solution.

It's not a full redox potential - for that you'll want [a full thermodynamic cycle](https://doi.org/10.1039/C4CP01572J) but it yields great trends that correlate very well for many organic redox potentials in acetonitrile.

Comment: +10 for quite a thorough answer to an unanswered but potentially very popular question. Useful to our users without a doubt!

Comment: Interestingly enough, this paper actually reports quite a few of the compounds we would consider using.  A better answer than even expected.